# Why does pasta dough need to be kneaded for such a long time?

Tags: dough, pasta

Some dough recipes caution that we shouldn't knead the dough for too long, lest it become too tough to be rolled as thin and wide as the recipe calls for. Why isn't the same thing true about pasta dough, which needs to be kneaded for more than 10 minutes?

Comment: @moscafj but some dough recipe says don't knead too much or else gluten develops and it will be hard to stretch the dough later. Very confusing.

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/26122/67

Comment: @alim1990 these recipes will be easier to shape and will taste less like standard pasta. You are free to choose what is more important to you.

Answer (score 1):

Kneading aids gluten development, which does facilitate dough stretch-ability.  You do need to let the dough rest, after kneading.  This allows for hydration, but also lets the gluten structure "relax" so that the dough can be stretched. Gluten development also impacts crumb texture.  So, for, say biscuits, you would not want to knead and develop gluten. For pasta and pizza you are looking for a different final texture/chew.

Comment: It took me a long time to learn the full need and benefit of a correct relax rest.  It really is key to many pastas after an adequate kneading.  It makes the whole hassle of pulling out the roller worth it.

Comment: So gluten will destroy the crumbly texture of biscuits ?

Comment: @alim1990 crumbly biscuits (the dough has hardly been kneaded) have a very loose gluten structure.